# Does Windows 10 provide sufficient virus and threat protection?

Tags: antivirus, windows-10, threat-mitigation

I am configuring a new laptop with Windows 10 Home and trying to determine if it is necessary to buy one of the [big antivirus packages](https://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2372364,00.asp) such as Norton, McAfee, etc. Is the security software that comes preinstalled in Windows 10 Home sufficient to protect against basic threats the average user is likely to encounter or would it be wise to use non-Windows virus and threat protection software?

Comment: *"... the average user ..."* - whatever this is. If this is a user who downloads software from random places on the internet just because it looks fun or claims to be some necessary software update then likely any AV is insufficient.

Comment: No, it does not. The 'average' user is too easy to get a virus now-days and Windows Defender was mostly created to protect the internal files of Window itself rather than generally protect the system.

Answer (score 2):

Windows defender is more than adequate for home use. I find its actually becoming a tad annoying as I will PoC malware techniques to understand them and defender keeps dropping my files in quarantine.

Really for the price and what it does you cannot go wrong with Windows defender.